# Heroku Deployment brings an Application Error

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

After deploying my django app through Heroku, I noticed that it was somewhat able to deploy successfully except when going to the actual website it gave me a , "Application Error." I'm not too sure what's going on here.

After running heroku logs --tail I receive this:

```
Initial release by user gkatashima@gmail.com
Release v2 created by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:30:45.368070+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user gkatashima@gmail.com

2018-07-05T23:30:45.235675+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:32:40.582279+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:32:40.582279+00:00 app[api]: Set SECRET_KEY config vars by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:38:37.214305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-bayou-56583.herokuapp.com
request_id=2f385349-63bf-4e90-aa33-97998d0ad3af fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T23:38:37.530260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-bayou-56583.her
okuapp.com request_id=d3d472c6-3cd2-42e7-bc50-1139c132ae31 fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T23:40:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:40:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-07-05T23:40:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-07-05T23:45:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:45:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-07-05T23:45:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-07-05T23:49:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:49:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-07-05T23:49:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-07-05T23:50:33.067651+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:50:33.067651+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:40.698020+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-horizontal-19399) by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:40.971583+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:40.698020+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:40.990748+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:40.971583+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 443be4f6 by user gkatashima@gmail.com
2018-07-05T23:51:46.385661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dj-project.wsgi`
2018-07-05T23:51:48.532406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-07-05T23:51:48.557178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-05T23:51:48.560346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-07-05T23:51:48.463890+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-07-05T23:51:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-05T23:51:53.251249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dj-project.wsgi`
2018-07-05T23:51:54.924365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-07-05T23:51:54.962595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-05T23:51:54.841282+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-07-05T23:52:03.564920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-bayou-56583.herokuapp.c
om request_id=74e9f483-be8d-4d16-9621-e1d8eb668d26 fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T23:52:04.395003+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-bayou-56583.
herokuapp.com request_id=cad7f90a-86bf-4a21-901a-091ad8c08eeb fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-06T00:27:32.232731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-07-06T00:27:39.288387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dj-project.wsgi`
2018-07-06T00:27:41.954658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-06T00:27:41.927523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-07-06T00:27:41.864355+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-07-06T01:25:37.932841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-07-06T01:25:45.696646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dj-project.wsgi`
2018-07-06T01:25:48.473549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2018-07-06T01:25:48.497875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-06T01:25:48.381155+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-07-06T01:25:48.381521+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2018-07-06T02:14:43.892793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-bayou-56583.herokuapp.c
om request_id=9d30efe9-565b-43e4-aeae-d52f67582164 fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-06T02:14:44.139620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-bayou-56583.
herokuapp.com request_id=b7494979-597f-4563-ad9e-35a1e00d2494 fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-06T02:17:54.983475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-bayou-56583.herokuapp.c
om request_id=1f46bda8-aa0d-40f4-a83c-e9a35fea19e1 fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-06T02:17:55.396662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-bayou-56583.
herokuapp.com request_id=728e533c-390a-4da4-8065-7bbd9e4ed201 fwd="76.103.249.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Is it possible that the gunicorn is not found or possibly the settings.py isn't right?

Comment: Is `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes it is, I redid a pip install gunicorn but, it's already there.

Comment: Can you post your requirements.txt and your Procfile?

Comment: argon2-cffi==18.1.0  
bcrypt==3.1.4
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
Django==2.0.5
django-bootstrap3==10.0.1
django-braces==1.13.0
Faker==0.8.15
gunicorn==19.9.0
misaka==2.1.0
Pillow==5.0.0
pycparser==2.18
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.4
six==1.11.0
text-unidecode==1.2'

Comment: Procfile: web: gunicorn socialnet.wsgi